# How do I test an ActionFilter?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, unit-testing, testing

I have an action filter called `TimeoutFilter` that I apply to my `BaseController':

```
[TimeoutFilter]
public abstract class BaseController: Controller
{
}
```

where

```
public class TimeoutFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    private static readonly int TimeoutSeconds;
    static TimeoutFilter()
    {
        int s;
        if (!int.TryParse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MvcActionTimeoutSeconds"], out TimeoutSeconds))
        {
            throw new WebConfigException("appSettings", "MvcActionTimeoutSeconds must be an integer.");
        }
    }

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Server.ScriptTimeout = TimeoutSeconds;
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}
```

Testing the config part is easy, but how do I test the timeout part? My gut tells me to declare  `TestController: BaseController`, and then in an action method on that controller, *somehow* check if the `HttpContext.Current.Server.ScriptTimeout` value is equal to the config value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you necessary need to test if the server actually timed out. But you can test if `HttpContext.Current.Server.ScriptTimeout` is set to the same value as in the configuration.

```
[TestMethod]
public void OnActionExecuting_SetTimeout_TimeoutIsTheSameAsConfig()
{
    var request = new HttpRequestMessage();

    var actionContext = InitializeActionContext(request);

    var filter = new TimeoutFilter();
    filter.OnActionExecuting(actionContext);

    Assert.AReEqual(HttpContext.Current.Server.ScriptTimeout, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MvcActionTimeoutSeconds"]);
}

// Code excerpt from http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1234000001708/ch17.html#_unit_testing_an_actionfilterattribute
private HttpActionContext InitializeActionContext(HttpRequestMessage request)
{
    var configuration = new HttpConfiguration();

    var routeData = new HttpRouteData(route,
        new HttpRouteValueDictionary
        {
            { "controller", "Issues" }
        }
    );

    request.Properties[HttpPropertyKeys.HttpRouteDataKey] = routeData;
    var controllerContext = new HttpControllerContext(configuration, routeData, request);
    var actionContext = new HttpActionContext
    {
        ControllerContext = controllerContext
    };

    return actionContext;
}
```

Comment: Interesting idea, thanks, but your code doesn't compile. I fixed the missing `route` instance in `InitializeActionContext`, and even then I still get the error "cannot convert from 'System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionContext' to 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionExecutingContext'".

Comment: I can't tell right now. Your code builds fine on my home machine, but not on my work machine, which is fresh. It might need some updates. +1 for your help, but I managed to resolve this quite nicely using Rhino Mocks. I will post it as soon as I can pull it from the repo.

Comment: It could be because of `[TestMethod]` attribute for `OnActionExecuting_SetTimeout_TimeoutIsTheSameAsConfig`. I was using MSTest, but you can change it to whatever unit test you are using.